# String path that represents user´s home folder

Tags: java, path, directory

I need to set a string of a path in a properties text file which will create a directory inside the current user's home folder(who's logged on). Obviously I cannot do this :

```
        C:\Users\user1
```

because the drive's name is always vary :(

PS I'm using Java

Comment: What language are you using? .NET? Java? ...?

Answer (score 11):

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

Comment: +1 Fast, but also *correct* answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

to get the current user's home directory.